# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null (navbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
// Get the navbar
let navbar = document.getElementById("navigation");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function stickyNavigation() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("-sticky");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("-sticky");
    }
}

$(window).scroll(stickyNavigation);
stickyNavigation();
```

I have some pages there is no navbar and it shows error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null". How to make a if/else statements for that?

I've tried this:

```
    if (navbar.length > 0) {

    }
```

But It didnt work.

Comment: try this  if (navbar) {

    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in some cases there is no navbar, use statement like this:

```
if (navbar) {
//some statements
} else {...}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I suppose this is an example))))).
instead of  if (navbar.length > 0) { use statement provided by me

Answer (score 1):

**You're trying to access length method on `null` which is not right.**

```
if (navbar) {
//Do something
    }
```

Since null is falsy value so if condition will automatically fail in case you don't have any navbar element.